# Jad/JadClipse for Scala?

Tags: scala, jad, jadclipse

Is there something equivalent or similar to Jad/JadClipse for Scala? It would be nice to be able to view the source for Lift from within Eclipse via "Open Declaration".

Comment: Why do you need Jad for this? You can just attach Lift sources to jar.

Comment: This has been giving me trouble. Possibly because I already have Jad installed. Right now I've just been using "mvn dependency:sources" to grab all the source jars and view them manually. Perhaps that is the best option for now.

Comment: I find it's the best option :) A little advice: it it's not working/too boring/takes too much time in eclipse - migrate to IDEA. It will make all this boring stuff for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any decompiler, but I think what you want to do just attach the source to the jar containing classes.

Just right-click on the lift-jar in the package explorer and choose properties. There you can specify a source location. I believe that an attached source location will override an installed jad-plugin.

If you're using maven and m2eclipse, you can simply right-click the lift-dep. -> Maven -> download sources. That will download the -sources.jar and automatically attach.

Comment: Reading the comments under the question, I suddenly remembered I might have had similar problems. I think it might be the case that you have to uninstall the jadclipse-plugin if it doesn't honor an attached source location.

Answer (score 0):

I man not sure you could get back the exact scala source, but at least you could try and see what the nsc bytecode looks like in Java.

[This thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-understanding-generated-bytecode-td2004108.html) mentions (not tested myself) the [Soot Eclipse plugin](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/eclipse/).

> So I might settle on the Eclipse plugin for Soot, which can for example display bytecode using the Grimp notation (well, the following screenshot shows Jimple, but conveys the idea):

[image]